# Execute one line only after previous animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a li element on hover using jquery. I want the li element to first change its dimensions(using CSS transitions for this) and then change its text. However, writing it in the hover function both performs at the same time thus bigger text appears even before the element has expanded.

I have tried using callback() for it but it just doesn't work, the text never changes. I have also tried using the settimeout() function for it and it seems to work correctly except when we quickly hover and the remove cursor from the element, in that case, it still changes the text.

JS:

```
$(".dl").hover(function() {
  $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).text());
  $(this).css({
    "width": "320px",
    "height": "70px",
    "background-color": "aliceblue"
  });
  let that = this;
  $(that).text("New Testing Text As a replacement").fadeIn(1000);
}, function() {
  $(this).css({
    "width": "160px",
    "height": "30px",
    "background-color": "rgb(237, 199, 183)"
  });
  $(this).text($(this).data('defaultText'));
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="devices-list">
  <li class="dl">Device one</li>
  <li class="dl">Device two</li>
  <li class="dl">Device three</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.dl {
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(237, 199, 183);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: width 0.6s, height 0.6s, background-color 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxt9L4yn/)

Comment: Something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/4rjmzesa/1/)

Comment: @ShadowFiend yea i tried that too but if you quickly hover then remove the cursor then the new text still stays.

Comment: Oh something like that. I think you can use `.is(":hover")` for that.. Try [this..](https://jsfiddle.net/v04pm735/)

Comment: @ShadowFiend Oh yea this works perfectly , i didn't knew we could use something like this . Thank you!. you can add this as an answer , i can mark that as one.

Answer (score 1):

Plese try this code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dl").hover(function(){
    $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).text());
    $(this).css({"width": "320px", "height": "70px", "background-color": "aliceblue"});
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).text("New Testing Text As a replacement").fadeIn(1000);
    },800);
    }, function(){
    $(this).css({"width": "160px", "height": "30px", "background-color": "rgb(237, 199, 183)"});
    $(this).text($(this).data('defaultText'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have already tried that but the problem is  if you quickly hover then remove the cursor then the new text still stays.